# Color inside fractions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new at this, so I'll apologize in advance for any stupidity.

I'm typing up basic math stuff, and I'm basically producing a fraction that reads (ax+b + cx+d)/(ex+f). I'd like the ax and cx be in one color and the b and the d to be in another. ax+b is defined as NUMERATOR1 and cx+d is NUMERATOR2, as is pretty clear below. The variables are individually below too.

```
expression: <var>Y</var> = \dfrac{<var>NUMERATOR1</var> - (<var>NUMERATOR2</var>)}{<var>DENOMINATOR</var>}

NUMERATOR1: ["+", ["*", COEFF1, X], CONST1]
```

Basically, I'd like to know how to make COEFF1*X a color of its own and CONST1 a different color.

Comment: You may be thinking of using javascript to run these calculations. html is a markup language and won't run processes like this... unless there's something new I never heard of

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Adding color to text should be straightforward enough, but I'm guessing you want to do this with code?  What language?  The more you can explain what you want to do, the better.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm using Javascript! Whoops. For example, when I placed a \blue{..} around <var>NUMERATOR1</var>, it changed the entire thing - now I'm just trying to figure out a way to change the individual components.

Comment: So are you asking how to display this equation in various colors? or are you asking to display the results of this in various colors depending on the output?

Comment: @KaiQing I'm asking how to display it in multiple colors.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a SPAN around any element you want to change color and give it a class name:

```
NUMERATOR1: ["+", ["*", <span class='colorA'>COEFF1</span>, X], CONST1]
```

Then create a CSS entry for that class in a stylesheet in the HEAD of your page:

```
<style>
.colorA {
    color:#ff0000;
}

... more styles ...

</style>
```

You probably want to have your page in two sections - a JavaScript section that does the actual calculations, and an HTML section that's just for display purposes that mirrors the same equation.